# Reverse multiple SED commands

Tags: linux, sed, hex

I got a Hexadecimal string
but this string has been modified by 6 SED commands.

I wonder if there is a simple way to revert these commands

I tried to reverse substitution by simply executing the sed command upside down

thanks a lot for the help

Comment: If the input file contains any of the replacement strings, it's not possible to reverse it. There's no way to tell whether a particular instance is the result of a replacement or was there originally.

Comment: And indeed, `prim66` contains all of the replacement strings except for `66`. So what you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: Wait a second. Is `prim66` the input file or the final result? It doesn't contain any of the source strings in the `sed` commands.

Comment: prim66 is the result after the sed operations, thanks for your answer but I think I have a clue, I have to test all the possiblities...see my response below

Comment: You should delete that question as it is asking for a solution to solve a step of "https://challengecybersec.fr/" challenge.

Comment: @pixis you are probably right, but the purpose of a challenge is to manage how to get the information. I won't give the answer ;-) I do not want the answer, just a clue

Comment: @maverick at least change the values to anonymize it so that it doesn't come up as the first result if someone is looking for a solution (?)

Comment: @pixis done ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a change with sed may not be reversible.

Here is a simple example:

```
s1 = "abcbd"
s2 = echo $s1 | sed s/b/c/
```

`s2` is now `acccd` and there is no way to guess which `c` characters were existing in the original string and must be kept and which must be changed back to `b`

It is the same with your string: when you see a `fb` in the final string, you cannot guess whether is was a `7f` or already a `fb` in the original string.

Comment: Thanks, ok but here my original String, is made with a couple of characters separated with ':'    so I don't see what's may be unreversible

Comment: ok, I think I have a possible answer...for example 7f is supposed to be replaced by fb but the inverse may not be true

Comment: If you've got a repeatable way to verify your result then you've only got `2^2 * 2^3 * 2^1 * 2^1 * 2^0 * 2^4 = 2048` possible combinations to test (the exponents are the number of occurence of each token that may or may not be the result of a sed substitution)

Comment: @maverick wrt `I think I have a possible answer.` - you actually have **THE** answer: if the replacement strings cannot exist in the original file then you'd trivially just run each sed command in reverse, but if they can then it can't be done. Given input of `fb:7f` to `sed 's/7f/fb/g'` the output is `fb:fb` and there is no way to tell from `fb:fb` if the original input was `fb:7f` or `fb:fb` or `7f:fb` or `7f:7f`.